# Aggregating pandas series into a DataFrame and visual representation

Tags: python, dataframe, data-visualization, series, graph-visualization

I have three pandas Series, called: `Col_data`, `C_PV_data` and `C_elec_data`. Each one has these values:

```
 Col_data:
 0    625814.205486
1    782267.756857
2    938721.308229
Name: 7, dtype: object
```

```
 C_PV_data:
 0    2039032.206909
1    2548790.258636
2    3058548.310363
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

```
 C_elec_data:
 0    1337523.743009
1    1671904.678761
2    2006285.614513
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I would like to aggregate them into a single DataFrame, to export that DataFrame to a **.xlsx** file, in which each column is called as the variable. For instance:

| Col_data | C_PV_data | C_elec_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 625814.205486 | 2039032.206909 | 1337523.743009 |
| 782267.756857 | 2548790.258636 | 1671904.678761 |
| 938721.308229 | 3058548.310363 | 2006285.614513 |

Finally, I would like to represent each column with a graph in which the central value is a line, and two dots over that line, for the lowest and hights value. For instance, the graph would be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here you go:

### Init

```py
Col_data = pd.Series([
    625814.205486,
    782267.756857,
    938721.308229])
C_PV_data = pd.Series([
    2039032.206909,
    2548790.258636,
    3058548.310363])
C_elec_data = pd.Series([
    1337523.743009,
    1671904.678761,
    2006285.614513])
```

### As a `df`

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [Col_data, C_PV_data, C_elec_data], axis=1,
    keys=['Col_data', 'C_PV_data', 'C_elec_data'])
>>> df
        Col_data     C_PV_data   C_elec_data
0  625814.205486  2.039032e+06  1.337524e+06
1  782267.756857  2.548790e+06  1.671905e+06
2  938721.308229  3.058548e+06  2.006286e+06
```

Side note: I always dislike repeats. The following alternative to the above is DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), but less clear perhaps:

```py
keys = ['Col_data', 'C_PV_data', 'C_elec_data']
d = locals()  # just for DRY...
df = pd.concat([d[k] for k in keys], axis=1, keys=keys)
```

### To xlsx

Assuming you have `openpyxl` installed:

```py
df.to_excel('foo.xlsx', index=False)
```

### Box plot

**Edit**: (and save as PNG)

```py
ax = df.loc[[0,1,1,1,2]].plot.box()
ax.figure.savefig('costs.png')
```

[image]

Comment: How could I save that figure? I use this command `plt.savefig('costs.jpg')` but the figure saved does not show the image

Comment: sure -- see edited answer..